# Can't load WP admin panel and can't figure out why..?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that is having some sort of an issue I can't seem to figure out.  When I try to load the admin panel I get the following:

> Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
>   should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
>   admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see
>   Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added
>   in version 3.3.) in
>   /home/airassoc/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3370
>
> Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
>   wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in
>   /home/airassoc/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3201
>
> Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use
>   wp_register_widget_control() instead. in
>   /home/airassoc/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3201
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/airassoc/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:3370) in
>   /home/airassoc/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1179

All of those notices are referring to core WP files, though, and WP itself has been updated to the latest version as of a week or two ago.

I'm thinking I must have something (theme or plugin) causing this, but the PHP notices aren't giving me any help.  I've been going through (from the server) and deleting any plugins I think may be causing it but I haven't had any luck.

Any tip on how to troubleshoot this sort of thing would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with theme. I think your theme is too old and haven't been update for a long time, what is why it is not supporting new function of wordpress

Comment: I'll see if I can change the theme from the DB and hopefully that'll help.  We're using the Accupress Lite theme, which I'm pretty sure is compatible, but we'll see.

Comment: I was able to get to the admin panel by disabling WP_DEBUG and going straight to wp-login.php in the URL instead of /wp-admin.  I've updated all plugins to the latest version and the problem hasn't gone away.  I do see there is a small update for the theme.  Hopefully that'll do it.  It's very out-of-date, though.

Comment: Well, shoot.  All plugins and the theme have been updated to the latest version and I'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if you have changed any files for your theme this can cause the dashboard and site to go down and not load, you may need to restore the default files for your theme you can do so by going to the public_html folder thru cpanel of your host and upload the theme files back again.